# Как отображать текст сайта, который я посетил, в виде колонки в 2 - 4 слова?

Tags: браузер, текст

Есть ли для этого расширение для браузера (любого)?

Answer (score 1):

Если это для скорости чтения, то есть напр. [Spreeder](http://www.spreeder.com/) — но с его расширением надо выделять на странице текст, который хотите быстро прочитать.